# JQuery Post to a .NET MVC App to Display Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I have an app that posts to my server using Jquery (Ajax) and receives and displays HTML data on the page. It's a pretty simple JQuery call as such:

```
function LoadStats(isUpdate) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: {
            {someData, removed for SF}
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#statsBox").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get a simple Google Chart to display in this box. The javascript does not seem to display correctly though when I do this. I am using the basic example from Google Charts like the following in a MVC View:

```
<div>HTML Here. Hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Year', 'Sales'],
              ['2004',  1000     ],
              ['2005',  1170     ],
              ['2006',  660       ],
              ['2007',  1030      ]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('statsBox'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

</script>
```

My initial attempt included putting the reference to google.com/jsapi script in the view itself, and that gave me an error that Google was not defined. So I put the reference to the API in the header of my page, which got rid of the error but now when it loads, it blanks out the screen. No errors, just a white blank page.

Keep in mind once I actually get the chart to work I will be populating it with data from the server, hence the reason I don't just put it in the page itself. What am I missing here? I have a feeling it has something to do with the setOnLoadCallback, since I'm using a jquery post to load up data there's got to be some other setting I need to set in order to display this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it definitely was an issue with the setOnLoadCallBack function. I simply removed it and replaced it with a simple

```
        $(function () {
            drawChart();
        });
```

I also had to load the chart on the page as opposed to the server. I just put this:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

On the server. Thanks to [this StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927722/google-charts-in-rails-3-1-ajax-partial?rq=1).